RavenDB index with child list
I want to create an index containing a child list from a different collection, but I'm getting "Map and Reduce functions of a index must return identical types."
This is what I got so far:
    public class PropertiesIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<PropertyIndexResult>
    {
        public PropertiesIndex()
        {
            // Map for Property
            AddMap<Property>(properties => from property in properties.Where(x => x.Status < 2)
                                           select new PropertyIndexResult
                                           {
                                               Id = property.Id,
                                               Images = new List<PropertyImage>()
                                           });

            // Map for PropertyImage
            AddMap<PropertyImage>(images => from image in images
                                            select new PropertyIndexResult
                                            {
                                                Id = image.PropertyId,
                                                Images = new List<PropertyImage> { image }
                                            });
            
            // Reduce function
            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by result.Id into g
                                select new PropertyIndexResult
                                {
                                    Id = g.Key,
                                    Images = g.SelectMany(x => x.Images ?? new List<PropertyImage>()).ToList()
                                };

            StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
        }
    }

The PropertyIndexResult looks like this:
public class PropertyIndexResult
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyImage>? Images { get; set; } = [];
}

And the PropertyImage:
public class PropertyImage
{
    public long PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string? Url { get; set; }
}

I'm using ravendb 6.0.3 and .net 8.0

Issue is under investigation
https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-22615/MultiMapReduce-index-error-Map-and-Reduce-function-types-should-be-identical

Thank you for redirecting my issue to the dev team directly @Danielle, I saw that the issue had been resolved by Michal, does that mean that the fix is live after the release of version 6.0.105?

The fix is now merged in the latest 6.0 branch.
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/pull/18880

A fix to the problem is provided here
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/pull/18880
